# Powershell Selenium: Unable to Locate Element on Amazon

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to create a Selenium script in Powershell that automatically buys something that I tell it to.  I've gotten it past finding the item, and clicking the Buy Now button, but then this window pops up and I've tried what seems like 3000 different ways of failing to click the Place your order button.  Web code to the right.  Appears to be the "turbo-checkout-pyo-button", but finding it by ID, XPath, CSSselector, etc have all failed for me.  It's not a wait issue.  I've even thrown in an explicit (and overly long) 5 second delay to be sure this field is present and "should" be clickable.  Any ideas?

I've tried all of these.  They're all followed by $placeYourOrderBtn.click() (and have all failed):

```
$placeYourOrderBtn = $ChromeDriver.FindElementByXpath("//*[@id='turbo-checkout-pyo-button']")

$placeYourOrderBtn = $ChromeDriver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='turbo-checkout-place-order-button']")

$placeYourOrderBtn = $ChromeDriver.FindElementByXPath("//span[text() = Place your order]")

$placeYourOrderBtn = $ChromeDriver.FindElementById("turbo-checkout-place-order-button-announce")

$placeYourOrderBtn = $ChromeDriver.FindElementById("turbo-checkout-pyo-button")

$placeYourOrderBtn = $ChromeDriver.FindElementByCssSelector("#turbo-checkout-pyo-button")
```

[image]

Comment: One new thing I've found is that I can't seem to pull any information off the window that pops up with the Place your Order button.  How do I change the focus?  I'm guessing that's what I need to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for a windows that sends email.  You have to click the button to open the new window, then use "SwitchTo()" to change to the new window.

[void]$Webdriver.SwitchTo().Window($WebDriver.WindowHandles[1])

You may have to read the window handles attribute and query each one to determine which one you need to open.